# ubuntu 20.04 wrong ip in LAN

Tags: networking, netplan, ip, lan, routing

After updating Ubuntu 20.04 and installing wireguard I'm facing an issue. My machine wasn't reachable via ssh and pings anymore.
`ping 192.168.178.42` (the LAN ip of the ubuntu machine) outputs:

```
$ ping 192.168.178.42
PING 192.168.178.42 (192.168.178.42) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.178.55 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.178.55 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.178.55 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.178.42 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, +6 errors, 100% packet loss, time 6274ms
pipe 4
```

so I went in physically and disabled ufw... still unreachable

the output of `ip a` is:

```
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK, UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_Ift forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid _lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP,LOWER _UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fa_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:31:bf:ba:7e:54 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.179.32/24 brd 192.168.179.255 scope global dynamic enp0s31f6
       valid_lft 18238sec preferred_lft 18238sec
    inet6 fd00::1:1a31:bfff:feba:7e54/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 7031sec preferred_lft 3431sec
    inet6 fe80::1a31:bfff:feba:7e54/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP› mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none
    inet 192.168.6.1/24 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP› mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:34:c5:78:af bra ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

which is wierd because i dont know where address `192.168.179.32` is coming from.
`192.168.178.42` used to be the ip the router assigned to ubuntu

`netstat -r` outputs:

```
# netstat -r
Kernel IP routing table
Destination      Gateway       Genmask         Flags  MSS Window  irtt Iface
default          fritz.box     0.0.0.0         UG     0   0       0    enp0s31f6
172.17.0.0       0.0.0.0       255.255.0.0     U      0   0       0    docker0
192.168.6.0      0.0.0.0       255.255.255.0   U      0   0       0    wg0
192.168.179.0    0.0.0.0       255.255.255.0   U      0   0       0    enp0s31f6
fritz.box        0.0.0.0       255.255.255.255 UH     0   0       0    enp0s31f6
```

and `ip r`:

```
# ip r
default via 192.168.179.1 dev emp0s31f6 proto dhcp src 192.168.179.32 metric 100
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
192.168.6.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.6.1
192.168.179.0/24 dev empos31f6 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.179.32
192.168.179.1 dev enpos31f6 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.179.32 metric 100
```

could the error be that my machine is thinking `192.168.179.32` is its local ip?
is `/etc/netplan/` wrong?

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

I initially thought this was an issue with my router, but all my other devices still have their `192.168.178.x` ip and are ping / ssh-able.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Does your computer have multiple ethernet ports? If so, if you plug the cable in the other port, the router will see a different MAC address. Check your router settings which MAC has been assigned the expected IP. Then check that MAC with the output of `ip a` link/ether.

Comment: Sounds like this might not be an ubuntu issue. Please check the settings of your Fritzbox. Is th “Guest” network enabled? Does it use the range `192.168.179.0/24`? Are you connected to `LAN4` of the Fritzbox? What do the network settins tell you about the old IP and the IP in the fritzbox?

Comment: @dummyuser i investigated futher and found out there is in fact a guest network using the `192.168.179.x` range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this is not an ubuntu issue.
Fritzbox uses the IP range `192.168.179.0/24` for the “Guest” network by default. For some - to me unknown - reasons you are connected to the Guest network and not to your internal network.

Possible Solutions:

1. Reconfigure the fritzbox and disable the Guest network
2. Use Lan Port 1-3 instead of LAN Port 4 at the Fritzbox (Port 4 is in the guest network) (depending on Fritzbox Version)
3. check any other option in the fritzbox

Reboot after implementation.